# Reverse array field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with a location field that was entered in the wrong order:

```
location: [38.7633698, -121.2697997]
```

When I try to place a 2d index on the field using ...

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({'location': '2d'});
```

... I get the following error because the latitude and longitude are reversed.

```
"err" : "location object expected, location array not in correct format",
"code" : 13654
```

How can I reverse this array for each document in the mongo shell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
db.loc.find().forEach(function (doc) {
    var loc = [ doc.location[1], doc.location[0] ]; 
    db.loc.update(doc, { $set: { location: loc } });
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Starting from MongoDB 3.4 we can use the [`$reverseArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reverseArray) operator to do this beautifully.

### Reverse the array:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [ 
        { "$project": { "location": { "$reverseArray": "$location" } } }
    ]
)
```

which yields:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("576fdc687d33ed2f37a6d527"), 
    "location" : [ -121.2697997, 38.7633698 ] 
}
```

### Update all documents

To update all the documents in your collection, you have a couple of options.

The first is to add a [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) stage to your pipeline and replace the old collection. In this case, you will need to explicitly include all the other field in the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)ion stage. The `$out` stage look like this:

```
{ "$out": "collection" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  **$push**

to reserve the array using the ***$each*** & ***$sort*** functionality of it

```
 db.getCollection('locations').updateMany({},
      { 
        $push: { 
                 'geo_point.coordinates': { $each: [ ], $sort: -1 }
               }
      });
```