# Recursive search on a collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, tree-structure

I have a list of documents in MongoDB with tree structure, where [Model Tree Structures with Parent References](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-parent-references/index.html) pattern used. I want a single aggregation query which returns ancestor list(till the root), given the 'name' property.

Structure:

```
{
  '_id': '1',
  'name': 'A',
  'parent': '',
},
{
  '_id': '2',
  'name': 'B',
  'parent': 'A',
},
{
  '_id': '3',
  'name': 'C',
  'parent': 'B',
},
{
  '_id': '4',
  'name': 'D',
  'parent': 'C',
}
```

Aggregation result:(Given, name = 'D')

```
{
  '_id': '4',
  'name': 'D',
  'ancestors': [{name:'C'}, {name:'B'}, {name:'A'}]
}
```

`Note:` I can't change the document structure now. It will cause many problems. I saw many solutions which suggest to use [Model Tree Structures with an Array of Ancestors](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-ancestors-array/index.html). But I cannot use it now. Is there any way to achieve it with the above pattern using single aggregation query? Thank you

Comment: Why is `_id` string?

Comment: @Styvane It's just an example. Actual doc will be having ObjectId

Comment: @RaR Is there something about Styvane's answer that doesn't work for you that's prompting the bounty?

Comment: @JohnnyHK Styvane's answer will work from MongoDB v3.4 I was looking for a way that works with MongoDB v2.6 onwards

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Starting from MongoDB 3.4, we can do this with the Aggregation Framework.

The first and most important stage in our pipeline is the [`$graphLookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/) stage. `$graphLookup` allows us to recursively match on the "parent" and "name" field. As result, we get the ancestors of each "name".

The next stage in the pipeline is the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match) stage where we simply select the "name" we are interested in.

The final stage is the [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields) or [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage where we apply an expression to the "ancestors" array using the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map) array operator.

Of course with the [`$reverseArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reverseArray) operator we [reverse our array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053975/reverse-array-field-in-mongodb) in order to get the expected result.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [ 
        { "$graphLookup": { 
            "from": "collection", 
            "startWith": "$parent", 
            "connectFromField": "parent", 
            "connectToField": "name", 
            "as": "ancestors"
        }}, 
        { "$match": { "name": "D" } }, 
        { "$addFields": { 
            "ancestors": { 
                "$reverseArray": { 
                    "$map": { 
                        "input": "$ancestors", 
                        "as": "t", 
                        "in": { "name": "$$t.name" }
                    } 
                } 
            }
        }}
    ]
)
```

Comment: Hi, how do I need to change this, if I am given name = 'A' instead of name = 'D'? I need all documents whose ancestor is A.

Comment: @user3629892, I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you mean you have 'A' instead of 'D'? well, if that's the case, simply replace 'D' by 'A' or even better, you can assign the *name* to a variable and use that variable in your pipeline.

Comment: What I meant was that I have entries that each reference their parent. Given a leaf node (with no children), i want to find its parent and the parent of the parent and so on... As input, I dont get the parent node, but the leaf node, so in the OP's example it would be D instead of A. I will try out your suggestion

Comment: Hi, i have a similar situation but, i have users with followers and those followers have many followers, i need get recursively followers of first user to down recursively.

Comment: I have one problem with this solution it does not maintain the correct. The order comes randomly

Answer (score 2):

If you are open to use client side javascript, you can use recursion on the mongo shell to achieve this:

```
var pushAncesstors = function (name, doc) {
  if(doc.parent) {
    db.collection.update({name : name}, {$addToSet : {"ancesstors" : {name : doc.parent}}});
    pushAncesstors(name, db.collection.findOne({name : doc.parent}))
  }
}

db.collection.find().forEach(function (doc){
  pushAncesstors(doc.name, doc);
})
```

This will give you complete hirearchy for all products. Sample output:

```
{ "_id" : "1", "name" : "A", "parent" : "" }
{ "_id" : "2", "name" : "B", "parent" : "A", "ancesstors" : [ { "name" : "A" } ] }
{ "_id" : "3", "name" : "C", "parent" : "B", "ancesstors" : [ { "name" : "B" }, { "name" : "A" } ] }
{ "_id" : "4", "name" : "D", "parent" : "C", "ancesstors" : [ { "name" : "C" }, { "name" : "B" }, { "name" : "A" } ] }
```

If your requirement is not to update the correct collection, insert the data in a diffferent collection and update there. The `pushAncesstors` function will change to:

```
var pushAncesstors = function (name, doc) {
  if(doc.parent) {
    db.outputColl.save(doc)
    db.outputColl.update({name : name}, {$addToSet : {"ancesstors" : {name : doc.parent}}});
    pushAncesstors(name, db.collection.findOne({name : doc.parent}))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I am open to using client side javascript. But, the above one will update the existing document, right? The need is to get the hierarchy but not to update the document.

Comment: Updated the answer to leave the current collection unmodified.

Comment: that's the classic example of bringing data to logic (code) which is super expensive. i'd suggest you to send your logic(code) to data, by using mongo apis (cheap op.).