# Count Recursively on a collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, recursion, tree, aggregation-framework

I have a list of documents in MongoDB with a tree structure. I want a single aggregation query which returns the count of all nested children, given an `_id` property.

Structure:

```
{
  '_id': '1',
  'parentId': null,
},
{
  '_id': '2',
  'parentId': '1',
},
{
  '_id': '3',
  'parentId': '1',
},
{
  '_id': '4',
  'parentId': '3',
}
```

Aggregation result: (given: `_id='1'`)

```
{
  total_children: 3
}
```

I understand that this probably requires a [`$graphLookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/) stage, and this question is very similar to [Recursive search on a collection in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40526148/recursive-search-on-a-collection-in-mongodb/40528543#40528543) but is backwards in a sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use below aggregation query.

Recursive lookup to locate all the children for a given _id followed by `$size` to count the chidren.

```
db.col.aggregate([
  {"$match":{"_id":"1"}},
  {"$graphLookup":{
    "from":col,
    "startWith":"$_id",
    "connectFromField":"_id",
    "connectToField":"parentId",
    "as":"children"
  }},
  {"$project":{"total_children":{"$size":"$children"}}}
])
```

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but what is `col` in the $graphLookup stage? edit: nevermind, that is my collection. Thank you!